# How to Create a Focus and Select Barcode Textbox in the UserControl Form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, user-controls, setfocus

How to Create a Barcode Focus and Select Textbox in the UserControl Form in vb.net. I've created a select textbox like the code below but it doesn't work and I don't want use form_load so I can only public sub new.

is there something wrong with my code?
the problem is that the textbox is not in the select position at the first time the form loads

```
Namespace project.Pages

    Partial Public Class PgItemTransfer
        Inherits UserControl

        Public Sub New()

            If Program.IsInDesignMode(Me) Then
                Return
            End If

            InitializeComponent()

            ColAvatar.FillWeight = 30.0!
            ColAvatar.Width = 30
            ColEdit.FillWeight = 30.0!
            ColEdit.Width = 46

            LoadData()
            
            BtxtBarcode.Focus()
            BtxtBarcode.Select()
            
        End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason that your code indenting is all over the place, despite the fact that VS will format it for you? You should aim to make it as easy as possible for us to help you and posting badly formatted code does not do that.

Comment: You need to provide a much more detailed explanation of your problem, including EXACTLY what you expect to happen and EXACTLY what does happen. *"it doesn't work"* is never an adequate problem statement.

Comment: @jmcilhinney , thanks reply from you, the problem is that the textbox is not in the select position at the first time the form loads

Comment: `BtxtBarcode` is not getting keyboard focus?

Comment: You can't affect the focus on the form when the user control is created because the focus is set well after that. You can handle the events of the form that the user control is on within the user control, so that's what you'd have to do in order to use code to do that. Alternatively, make the `Textbox` the first control in the Tab order in the user control and then the user control the first in the Tab order on the form and it will happen on its own.

Comment: @ÉtienneLaneville , `BtxtBarcode is not getting keyboard focus? ` Yes, that's true what you said.